# Exception thrown in function using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I've got a simple Patient class with properties like

```
 public int PatientId { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
```

and a function to return a random patient based on their PatientId like

```
 public static Patient GetRandomPatient(IEnumerable<Patient> patList)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int patientValue = r.Next(patList.Min().PatientId, patList.Max().PatientId);
            //return from g in patList
            //       where g.PatientId == patientValue
            //       select g;
            var test = from g in patList
                       where g.PatientId == patientValue
                       select g;
            return (Patient)test;
        }
```

The commented out lines are the first attempt at returning the patient whose PatientId was chosen by the Random class.  That didn't compile and I was given the error
`Cannot implicitly convert type... (are you missing a cast)?`
So then I ran the iteration that isn't commented out and got the exception
`At least one object must implement IComparable`.

So then I tried this as my return statement

```
 Patient testPatient = patList.First(x => x.PatientId == patientValue);
 return testPatient;
```

This compiles without an error, but when I run it I get the same exception that one object must implement IComparable.

I would like to know two things
 1. What seems to be the concept that I'm not quite getting here with regard to returning a single object from a list using LINQ syntax (In this situation, each PatientId is unique so the return statement could only possible return a single Patient object)?
 2. Why does the code

```
Patient testPatient = patList.First(x => x.PatientId == patientValue);
 return testPatient;
```

compile and give no compiler errors, but bombs with the same exception the other iterations have?

Main function

```
         List<Patient> patientList = new List<Patient>();
    patientList.Add(new Patient() { PatientId = 101, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Jacosdfasdfasdfb" });
                    patientList.Add(new Patient() { PatientId = 100, FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Wilson" });
                    patientList.Add(new Patient() { PatientId=102, FirstName="Max",LastName="Payne"}); 
//Call that bombs the program Console.WriteLine(Patient.GetRandomPatient(patientList).PatientId);
```

Comment: Either pass the random instance as argument to the method or use a static field in your class. Otherwise it will not generate random values if you call `GetRandomPatient` in a loop because it's seeded with the curent time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: And note that `Random` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @SLaks could you expand on those implications?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx

Comment: @SLaks Jon Skeet will be a demi god in the next generation :)

Comment: `GetRandomPatient` sounds like the method the local AM/PM clinic uses when calling people from the waiting room.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, your `.Min()` and `.Max()` calls don't make sense.
You can only call `Min()` or `Max()` on a collection of objects that can be compared to each-other.

Instead, you need to call them on a collection of IDs:

```
patients.Select(p => p.PatientId).Min()
```

You can also replace your entire function with the simpler (and faster)

```
return patients.ElementAt(rand.Next(patients.Count()));
```

Comment: Ahh, I see what I've done.  What I MEANT to do was have the Max and Min calls find the Max and Min PatientId so the random number generator wouldn't select a value outside of that range.  I can see now where what I did makes no sense.

Comment: Note that `Min` and `Max` each take selectors as parameters, so you don't need to call `Select` first, you can just pass `p => p.PatientId` to those methods directly.

Comment: @Servy: Yes; I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the first statement I am curious of the rest of the error message, what types cannot be implicitly converted, my bet is that PatientId is string or nullable int (int?) while you are compating with a normal integer.

```
    //return from g in patList
    //       where g.PatientId == patientValue
    //       select g;
```

Comment: You can see from the code in the Main function that PatientId is an int.  The problems lies with my call to the Next() function of the Random class.  I'm meant to get the max and min PatiendIds, didn't do so.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that now, disregard my answer.